# Kafka consumer from specific offset

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

Here is the code but i don't got proper result data not come properly from specific offset what to do please let me knoew if any one know

```
ConsumerRecords<String, AccountHolder> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1000));

        if (flag) {
            //consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("sudotest", 0), 29061);
            consumer.seek(new TopicPartition("sudotest",0), 2854);


            flag = false;
        }

        for (ConsumerRecord<String, AccountHolder> record : records)
            System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `i don't got proper result data not come properly from specific offset `?

Answer (score 0):

Is this code inside a loop? From what I see you are first polling (so getting actual messages) and then you seek to a specific offset. If you are not doing this code in a receiving loop, you have to seek first and then calling the poll for getting messages.

Comment: it will give error if i use seek before poll like i show you here >>>>>>>>>>

Comment: i done this already but it's not working if you hv any program so please share it

Comment: what kind of error? what do you mean "it's not working"? what is the output? please share more details.